# Check Equality Over Time Within Groups

Tags: r

How can I write a for loop or use a function that will check equality over time by group within my data?

I have time series data by congressional district arranged like the small piece below, but with much more data of course:

```
dput(droplevels(head(CongressionalData[1:5],20)))
structure(list(state_dist = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("AK_1", 
"AL_1", "AL_2", "AL_3"), class = "factor"), electionyear = c(2002L, 
2004L, 2006L, 2008L, 2010L, 2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2008L, 2010L, 
2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2008L, 2010L, 2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2008L, 
2010L), cong = c(108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 
111L, 112L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
112L), name = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("BONNER", 
"BRIGHT", "EVERETT", "ROBY", "ROGERS", "YOUNG"), class = "factor"), 
    republican = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("state_dist", 
"electionyear", "cong", "name", "republican"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to only make comparisons within districts, so I want to check if a district switched between republican and democratic representatives. For simplicity's sake, I'd just like to generate a list with 0's or 1's for switch or not switch. My first thought was a for loop like:

```
    group1 <- c()
for (i in 1:(nrow(CongressionalData) - 1)) {
      if (CongressionalData$republican[i] == CongressionalData$republican[i+1]) {
        group1 <- c(group1, 1)
      }
      else {
       group1 <- c(group1, 0)
      }
    }
```

But this compares each districts last election with the next district's first election.

I've seen elsewhere that it is rarely a good idea to use for loops in R, but I have very little sense for what functions would work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data.table` package for this type of transformation. Since you are comparing a column between rows, you will need the `shift` function which generate a lagged vector of **republican** column in this case. And the `Reduce` function with `==` will then compare the original and lagged version of the column. If they are equal, return true, otherwise false. The `as.integer` function coerce the logical value into `1` and `0`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(CongressionalData)[, group1 := as.integer(Reduce("==", shift(republican, n = 0:1, type = "lag"))), .(state_dist)]
CongressionalData
    state_dist electionyear cong    name republican group1
 1:       AK_1         2002  108   YOUNG          1     NA
 2:       AK_1         2004  109   YOUNG          1      1
 3:       AK_1         2006  110   YOUNG          1      1
 4:       AK_1         2008  111   YOUNG          1      1
 5:       AK_1         2010  112   YOUNG          1      1
 6:       AL_1         2002  108  BONNER          1     NA
 7:       AL_1         2004  109  BONNER          1      1
 8:       AL_1         2006  110  BONNER          1      1
 9:       AL_1         2008  111  BONNER          1      1
10:       AL_1         2010  112  BONNER          1      1
11:       AL_2         2002  108 EVERETT          1     NA
12:       AL_2         2004  109 EVERETT          1      1
13:       AL_2         2006  110 EVERETT          1      1
14:       AL_2         2008  111  BRIGHT          0      0
15:       AL_2         2010  112    ROBY          1      0
16:       AL_3         2002  108  ROGERS          1     NA
17:       AL_3         2004  109  ROGERS          1      1
18:       AL_3         2006  110  ROGERS          1      1
19:       AL_3         2008  111  ROGERS          1      1
20:       AL_3         2010  112  ROGERS          1      1
```

Comment: Yes this is basically what I'm looking for. Could you explain what this code is doing? I'd like to be able to use this strategy in the future.

Comment: You should put `library(data.table)` somewhere

Comment: @Frank, Yep, just added it. Just added the explanation. Hopefully it's clear.